# Fingerprint scanner problem

Tags: drivers, kernel, fingerprint-reader

I am using asus vivobook pro K3500p model with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (5.19.0-35-generic)
but fingerprint sensor isn't working. is there any existing driver for that.
lsusb result: Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

That device is [listed](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) in the "Supported devices" in the "development version" of libfprint (which enables finger print readers). But it's not (or may not be) available in the stable releases.

So chances are it may work, or may not, but it's not well supported in Ubuntu 22.04 yet (and may never be).